# Get total (video durations) Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am building a Laravel app in which I upload videos.

To recover the duration of each video, I use the following package which is very good: https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3/

Where I need help is to get the total duration of all the videos and I have no idea how to handle this.

Here is an image that illustrates my research:

[image]

And this is how I call GetID3 in my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Managers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class VideoManager
{


    public function getVideoDuration($Videofile)
    {
        $getID3 = new \getID3();
        $pathVideo = 'storage/chapitres-videos/' . Auth::user()->id . '/' . $Videofile;
        $fileAnalyze = $getID3->analyze($pathVideo);
        $playtime = $fileAnalyze['playtime_string'];

        return $playtime;
    }
}


    $Videofile = $this->videoManager->videoStorage($request->file('video'));
    $lecture->video = $Videofile;
```

Comment: Are you analyzing your files with every view or are you storing the times in a table?

Comment: Thanks Repox. The times are stored in table I called Courses

Comment: Can you elaborate how these are stored? As seconds? As hh:mm:ss?

Comment: They're stored in seconds.